# Best way to use Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript

I plan to "compress" my JavaScript code and merge it into one file. I use Google Closure Compiler for "compressing" JS. But what is the best way to use it - merge all .js files into one .js file and then use Compiler or Compile each .js file and then merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure Compiler does the merging. You don't have to do that manually. Just pass it the name of each source file and it does the rest.

(In fact the second approach (compile each file separately) doesn't even work if you use advanced optimizations because the compiler needs all scripts to make the optimizations.)